# Prevent LinkButton post back OnClientClick not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know there are plenty of answers surrounding this topic but I just cannot get this to work.

I need to prevent a link button posting back and the following code is not working. The code is definitely being hit in all the required places.

Link button definition:

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="NavHelp" OnClientClick="showConfirm(event);" OnClick="NavHelp_Click" ToolTip="Help" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Javascript function (definitely being hit)

```
function showConfirm(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

However after `showConfirm` returns false the link button still posts back to the server side `NavHelp` method.

As a side note, I also put a breakpoint in the `__doPostback` method generated by .NET and it does get hit after `showConfirm` returns false.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, figured it out. I needed to include the return statement in the OnClientClick attribute:

```
OnClientClick="return showConfirm(event);"
```

NOT

```
OnClientClick="showConfirm(event);"
```

Answer (score 1):

incidentally, you can use your original code, but rather than using `event.stopPropagation()` you can use `event.preventDefault()`

so your code would be

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="NavHelp" OnClientClick="showConfirm(event);" OnClick="NavHelp_Click" ToolTip="Help" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

function showConfirm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

read some more on event.preventDefault() vs event.stopPropagation()
 here : http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events

basically the preventDefault prevents the elemnt from carrying out its dfault action, i.e. visting a link or submitting a form, while stoppropagation allows the dfault action to occur, BUT doesn't inform any parent elements that it has happened.

i created a little jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XgSXr/ that shows you the prevent default, this should allow you to put in your own javascript logic, display modals etc, before successfully pushing through the link click.

Comment: This certainly doesn't work for me. Then again, returning false doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="NavHelp" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="showConfirm(event);" OnClick="NavHelp_Click" ToolTip="Help" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<script>
    $("#NavHelp").click(function(event) {
        if (showConfirm()) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Return statement in `onClientClick Javascript Event`

```
OnClientClick="return showConfirm(event);"
```

So when showConfirm return false then request will not be transer to server and page not postback.